# Excel Javascript randomly skips Range formatting when run through loop

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I've a datasets ranging from 1 to 10,000. I am trying to format one of the cel by running through loop 1000 times to update 100 records. However, while using office javascript API, it randomly skips formatting in one of the cell. Here is my sample code:
Assume start at j=0:
I've first column in excel that has 1 to 10000 records all sorted.

```
window.Excel.run(async (context) => {
      const currentWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      var range = currentWorksheet.getUsedRange(); // getRange to match indexes
      var k = j * 100;
      for(var i=k; i < k + 100; i++) {
          let index = i + 1;
          var foundRange = range.find(index + "", {
            completeMatch: true, // find will match the whole cell value
            matchCase: false, // find will not match case
            searchDirection: 'forward' // find will start searching at the beginning of the range
         });      
          var row = foundRange.getEntireRow();
          var column = row.getColumn(3);
          column.format.fill.color = '0000FF';
      }
      return context.sync()
        .then(function() {
          console.log('Synching changes on dataset: ' + j);
        });
  });
```

However, it randomly skips formatting on some of the cells in 3rd column. Could someone please help in this?

Comment: What is the value of `j`?

Comment: Let's assume j starts at 0.

Comment: To help diagnose, can you list the indices of specific rows which were skipped?  There is a possibility it is not as random as it first appears.

Comment: Rows like 18, 24, 37, 40, 47 ...

Comment: Is it always the same rows that are skipped or does it change each time you run it?

Comment: It does change when I run again.